# Bitmap not saved correctly (from Android's Canvas)

Tags: android, opengl-es, canvas, fonts, bitmap

---

I changed my question a bit.

EDIT:

```
// make textures from text
public static void createTextureFromText(GL10 gl, String text, String texName) {

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    p.setTextSize(32 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    // get width and height the text takes (in px)
    int width = (int) p.measureText(text);
    int height = (int) p.descent();

    // Create an empty, mutable bitmap based on textsize
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    // get a canvas to paint over the bitmap
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    bmp.eraseColor(Color.CYAN); //Cyan for debugging purposes

    //draw the text
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, p);


    // save image - for debugging purposes
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

    // create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        // write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      .... make texture

}
```

I now have this code in use for creating textures from given text (this is just partially).
But I found the fault lies somewhere in the Bitmap creation. I now save the Bitmap on the sd-card, to see how it turns out and found I get a ALL Cyan bitmap (672B, 164x7 are the dimensions).

Does Anyone see why it doesn't create an Bitmap with text on it? What can I be doing wrong?

You'll be a hero if you could help me :)

Comment: I don't know if it's a good solution, but if you create a TextView with your text (without displaying it on screen) you could measure that view, create your bitmap with those dimensions and then use it to draw on the canvas created with the bitmap (textview.draw(canvas)). You would end up with a bitmap exactly fitting the text. I don't know about how effective this would be though.

Comment: The textview would adapt to whatever font size/spacing you have, so it could work...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#eraseColor(int)  --> says "Fills the bitmap's pixels with the specified Color."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your text height calculation is wrong. The 'descent' measurement is just the portion of text below the baseline (i.e. the tails of 'g' and 'q' etc). The correct height is ascent+descent, except that since ascent is negative you want:

```
int height = (int) (p.descent() + -p.ascent());
```

Secondly, when you drawText() the y coordinate you give it is where the baseline goes, it is not the top or bottom edge. So if you want to fill a bitmap that's just big enough to hold the text, your y coordinate should also be `-p.ascent()`.

Comment: Awesome! This stalled me for more than a week, and you managed to solve it for me :D Apparently I just needed to know the proper meanings of the methods. Thanks!